# get the values of a foreign key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, ado.net

Hi is there an easy way to get the values of a foreign key, without writing sql queries.

I generated the code with the help of my mssql database (ADO.NET).
Here's an example for clarification

order table:

```
id customer_fk
1  100
2  105
```

customer table:

```
id   name
100  Walter
105  White
```

view:

```
@model ...order
...
@customer_fk
```

@customer_fk delivers eg. "100" instead of "Walter"

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are required to use ADO.NET, but to accomplish what you want, without writing sql, you'll need to use some kind of ORM, such as EntityFramework.

You will need to write LINQ, which generates SQL and since EF will know about the relationship between the two tables, you will have access to the "name" property in the customer table.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to SQL might be a good option, since you're using MS SQL.  Just add the DataContext item to your project, and drag/drop the tables from your server.  Then you should be able to write something like:

```
public ActionResult Order(int orderId)
{
    using (MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext())
    { 
        var loadOptions = new LoadOptions();
        loadOptions.LoadWith<order>(o => o.customer);
        context.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
        var theOrder = context.orders.Where(order => order.id == orderId).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(theOrder);
    }
}
```

But if you're already using ADO.Net, maybe just write the query?  It's not that difficult:

```
SELECT order.*, customer.name
FROM order INNER JOIN customer ON order.customer_fd = customer.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in Entity Framework (or some other similar ORM), you can write a LINQ query that joins to your foreign key table:

```
var customerOrders = 
  from o in context.Orders
  join c in context.Customers on o.customer_fk equals c.ID
  select new { OrderID = o.ID, CustomerName = c.Name };
```